# A-star variation for complex maps

Tags: a-star

I am working on a path-finding project in which, I have to implement single source multiple destination (just like in electric circuit connection). Also there are lots of source nodes in my single map. The Map in the program is a simple 2D map with equal movement cost. The Map is of 952 X 400 (Width X Height). I have used A-star algorithm to find path (may or may not be shortest path). The problem is that sometimes the A-star failed to find the path , when the connection in the circuit gets complex. Can any one suggest me any variation of A-star which will solve this problem. Please Help!!!

Comment: A-star never fails to find a path (provided that a valid path exists). Worst case it's just slow (specifically it's slower than a simple BFS). So your code has a bug. Fix it.

Comment: Yes, you are completely true my friend. But in my project, I want to have path finding for circuit connection, and for which if circuit connection gets complex, then A-star fails to find the path. I just want an variation of A-star, that will solve this problem. Sorry, I didn't mention that earlier.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). But your question is still not clear.  Perhaps an example map would help clarify the question.

Comment: Actually friend , I want to create a simulator for electronic circuit. In that project, I want to have wire connection which is done by A-star algorithm. But when some complex circuit is implemented then, the A-star fails to find path

Comment: Barring any memory limitations, A* will fail to find a path for only one of two reasons: 1.) the implementation is incorrect, or 2.) no path exists. So, can you please provide additional information? Specifically: Is your system running out of memory? Are you using your own implementation of A* or are you using a well-established library? Can you verify that the path does in fact exist? Finally, please post at least a minimal, working example that we can use to focus our attention. Otherwise, I'm afraid this question is incomplete and it would be appropriate to remove it.